# Stratified Sample error

Tags: r, sample

I'm trying to replicate a code I found on [here](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/sampling/html/strata.html).

The goal is trying to adapt it to a bigger database to get a stratified sample.

The sampling frame is stratified by region within state.

```
data <- rbind(matrix(rep("nc",165), 165, 1, byrow=TRUE),
              matrix(rep("sc", 70),  70, 1, byrow=TRUE))
data <- cbind.data.frame(data, c(rep(1,100), rep(2,50), rep(3,15),
                                 rep(1,30), rep(2,40)), 1000*runif(235))
names(data) <- c("state", "region", "income")


library(sampling)
s <- strata(data, c("region", "state"), size=c(10,5,10,4,6), method="srswor")
```

On this point, I get the following error:

```
> Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

I don't know what this error is about.  Any help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: Is the sample code you provided above supposed to replicate the error? It runs fine for me. `data` is `235-by-3`
 and `s` is `35-by-5`.

Comment: Even if flodel is right about your code, I have to say, for a first post this is a well put together question. Bravo sir. It even seems as though you may have [read about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) how to post before doing so.

Comment: Agree, so not answering my question would ruin it a bit :-)

Comment: Is this question resolved or not? If not, please update it in such a way that others are able to replicate the problem you are facing.